# How to allow Googlebot to read bundled css for my meteor application

Tags: css, meteor, seo, googlebot

I recently got a bunch of errors from the mobile google bot saying my site is not mobile friendly, and I determined that it is because it is not correctly loading the .css file.

I see that the bundled css is at the link https://www.make.toys/f8e6e67664ba048af3f1ae3b45e6f925a2c16bfe.css?meteor_css_resource=true

which I can load in a browser, but when I have any robot service try to load it it just returns

```
.meteor-css-not-found-error { width: 0px;}
```

I am using prerender.io which may be related, but I tried to have it ignore the .css file which doesn't seem to change anything.

Is there a way to make sure that Mobile Google bot can read my css file?

Comment: The bundled css at the link you posted also returns `.meteor-css-not-found-error { width: 0px;}` for me, for what that's worth.

Comment: Interesting, it opens just fine for me on any browser I try, I am very confused on how this works